# Move element on resize

Tags: javascript, parallax, onresize

I have a black box

`<div id="blackbox" style="margin-left:0px; background-color:black; width:20px; height:20px;">`

onresize, each 1px decrement from screen.width should increment 'blackbox'.margin-left by 2px.

A parallax triggered by resize

Need to translate this to javascript

```
    function move() {
        var screenwidth = screen.width
        var innerwidth = window.innerwidth
        var x = screenwidth - innerwidth
        document.getElementById("blackbox").style.marginLeft = (x * 2) + "px";
    }
        window.onresize = move;
```

Comment: The `window.onresize = surf;` assignement have to be called **outside** of the function (once function defined)!

Comment: Can you describe what is not working?

Comment: yes i can, the code i just posted is not working

Comment: "not working" is a very weak description of "how" and what in is is not working.

Comment: If I knew exactly what was not working I would fix it myself

Comment: No. if you knew the *error* you would fix it. The *behaviour* that is not working as desired you know, otherwise you would not consider the code not to be working. Can you describe what what is not according to the expectation? I am not nitpicking, just asking you to provide information needed to someone be able to answer your question appropriately.

Comment: Sure, on resize, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case sensitivity issue. The property you're looking for is "innerWidth", with a capital "W", and not "innerwidth". Adjusting your code:

```js
function move() {
  var screenwidth = screen.width
  var innerwidth = window.innerWidth
  var x = screenwidth - innerwidth
  document.getElementById("blackbox").style.marginLeft = (x * 2) + "px";
}
window.onresize = move;
```

```html
<div id="blackbox" style="margin-left:0px; background-color:black; width:20px; height:20px;">
```